# Get the dictionary values for every key in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a list:

```
a = ['apple', 'carrot']
```

and a dictionary:

```
d ={'apple': [2,4], 'carrot': [44,33], 'orange': [345,667]}
```

How can I use the list **a** as a key to lookup in the dictionary **d**? I want the result to be written to a comma-separated textfile like this

```
apple,    carrot
2,        44
4,        33
```

---

Corrected the a-list from a = ['apple', 'orange'] to a = ['apple', 'carrot']

Comment: No, it's a simplified version of a problem I'm trying to solve... The apples and carrots are just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Your title is misleading. As far as i understand, you want to get the dictionary values for every key in a list, correct?

Comment: That is correct! and I want them printed out column-wise. There can be a random number of keys in the list.

Comment: Are you assuming that every element of `a` will be present as a key in `d`?

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the second output column be "orange" not "carrot"? (and with 345, 667 instead of 44, 33 underneath it)

Comment: That is correct... I will correct it

Comment: @msw: Every element of a will be present yes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know other people have been faster and their solutions are similar, but here's my take (take it or leave it):

```
a = ['apple', 'orange']

d ={'apple': [2,4], 'carrot': [44,33], 'orange': [345,667]}

fo = open('test.csv','w')
fo.write(',\t'.join(a)+'\n')
for y in xrange(len(d[a[0]])):
    fo.write(',\t'.join([str(d[i][y]) for i in a])+'\n')

fo.close()
```

which generates the file test.csv:

```
apple,  orange
2,      345
4,      667
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a = ['apple', 'orange']
d ={'apple': [2,4], 'carrot': [44,33], 'orange': [345,667]}

print ',\t'.join(a)
for row in zip(*(d[key] for key in a)):
    print ',\t'.join(map(str, row))
```

Output:

```
apple,  orange
2,      345
4,      667
```

Comment: What does the * in the zip-expression do?

Comment: Thanks.  I learned something today.

williamx - check out http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @williamx The * makes it so the values are passed as separate arguments to zip(), instead of passing one argument containing all of the values.  It's documented here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 1):

Question is very old, but for future visitors I'd suggest using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get values of dict **d** for keys **k** in list **a**:

```
values = [ d[k] for k in a ]
```

Comment: This is essentially what the highest rated answer by @DanielStutzbach already does. Rather than a list comprehension, it uses a generator expression, but there's very little difference in this context.